# Store User data temporary on ASP.Net MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing an ASP.Net MVC website, but I need some help figuring out how to go about a problem I'm having. The problem is when the user is logged in (it gets the information from a MySQL database), I need it to save all the user's information and the company's info. But I need to access it from multiple Views and Models. So what is the correct way to use do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store that information in `Global.asx` so that it will be available anywhere in the project.

But the only thing is that you need to mention the properties in `Global.asx` before execution.

Comment: Okay. Do you have an example of doing it. Because im quit new at ASP.Net MVC.